# How to pass variable from the controller to bots file

Tags: c#, botframework

I am trying to pass an id value from my controller to my bot file.
E.g.

```
[Route("api/chatbot/{chatBotID}")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task PostAsync(int chatBotID)
        {

            // Delegate the processing of the HTTP POST to the adapter.
            // The adapter will invoke the bot.
            await Adapter.ProcessAsync(Request, Response, Bot);

        }
```

```
      protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {


            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(ActivityTypes.Typing);
            Thread.Sleep(2500);

            if (turnContext.Activity.Text == "Red")
            {
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("Hey");
            } 

            var reply = MessageFactory.Text("Is there anything else I can help you?");

            reply.SuggestedActions = new SuggestedActions()
            {
                Actions = new List<CardAction>()
            {
                new CardAction() { Title = "Red", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack, Value = "Red" },
                new CardAction() { Title = "Yellow", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack, Value = "Yellow" },
                new CardAction() { Title = "Blue", Type = ActionTypes.ImBack, Value = "Blue" },
            },
            };
            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);



        }
```

I need to pass the chatBotID to the bot file to print out the user-id.
I have tried a few different solutions for asp.net core, but nothing seems to work. Any ideas

Comment: What channel are you targeting? And can you explain why you need a bot ID beyond the ID that's already in the `from` field of the activity?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are registering your bot as transient, and injecting it to the webapi controller via DI.

If that's the case, you can implement a public method in your Bot class to take the bot id (e.g. `SetBotId`).

Then in `PostAsync` function, you can call `Bot.SetBotId(chatBotId)` right before you call `Adapter.ProcessAsync`.

Comment: If you don't have a lot of "bot ids" to manage and they behave differently, I would highly suggest you to create different Bot classes and attach them onto different controllers.

Comment: Just a design consideration. If your bots are behaving the same, this approach is OK. However if bot1 is pure QnA, bot2 takes actions based on intents and uses multi turn dialogs, then it's not a good idea to put these into the same bot and do if/else.
In this case you can create multiple bots each having different behavior, and their own interfaces (inherited from IBot). Register them in DI - AddTransient(IBotQnA, BotQnA), AddTransient(IBotLuis, BotLuis). Now you can inject them to their own controllers and their logic are fully separated.